# Does pandas left merge preserve row order in the left df

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Suppose df1 has a column named A and contains many duplicate values in that column. Suppose df2 has a column named A but every value in its column is unique.

I would like to perform a merge that looks like:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='left')
```

Am I guaranteed that the row order in the resulting dataframe is the same as that of df1? On any small example I try it seems to work, but on the actual large example I am working on the order seems to be getting messed up and I am having to use:

```
df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on='A', how='left').set_index('index').sort_index()
```

Comment: pass `validate='m:1'` and find out whether your assumption is true

Comment: The assumption is true

Comment: In the specific snippet you have there, if `validate='m:1'` is true, it _should_ retain the order of the data in `left`, even without the `sort_index` call